# Simulate Compound poisson process in r

Tags: r, simulation

I'm trying to simulate a compound Poisson process in r. The process is defined by $ \sum_{j=1}^{N_t} Y_j $ where $Y_n$ is i.i.d sequence independent $N(0,1)$ values and $N_t$ is a Poisson process with parameter $1$. I'm trying to simulate this in r without luck. I have an algorithm to compute this as follows: 
Simutale the cPp from 0 to T:

Initiate: $ k = 0 $

Repeat while $\sum_{i=1}^k T_i < T$

Set $k = k+1$

Simulate $T_k \sim exp(\lambda)$ (in my case $\lambda = 1$)

Simulate $Y_k \sim N(0,1)$ (This is just a special case, I would like to be able to change this to any distribution)

The trajectory is given by $X_t = \sum_{j=1}^{N_t} Y_j $ where $N(t) = sup(k : \sum_{i=1}^k T_i \leq t )$

Can someone help me to simulate this in r so that I can plot the process? I have tried, but can't get it done.

Comment: Are you able to make use of `rnorm`, `rexp,` and `while`? It may be slow, but undifferent from any other programming language. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi, I have the same question here, how would you simulate Y from any distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cumsum` for the cumulative sums that determine the times N_t as well as the X_t.  This illustrative code specifies the number of times to simulate, `n`, simulates the times in `n.t` and the values in `x`, and (to display what it has done) plots the trajectory.

```
n <- 1e2
n.t <- cumsum(rexp(n))
x <- c(0,cumsum(rnorm(n)))
plot(stepfun(n.t, x), xlab="t", ylab="X")
```

[image: Figure]

This algorithm, since it relies on low-level optimized functions, is fast: the six-year-old system I tested it on will generate over three million (time, value) pairs per second.

---

That's usually good enough for simulation, but it doesn't quite satisfy the problem, which asks to generate a simulation out to time T.  We can leverage the preceding code, but the solution is a little trickier.  It computes a reasonable upper limit on how many times will occur in the Poisson process before time T.  It generates the inter-arrival times.  This is wrapped in a loop that will repeat the procedure in the (rare) event the time T is not actually reached.

The additional complexity doesn't change the asymptotic calculation time.

```
T <- 1e2            # Specify the end time
T.max <- 0          # Last time encountered
n.t <- numeric(0)   # Inter-arrival times
while (T.max < T) {
  #
  # Estimate how many random values to generate before exceeding T.
  #
  T.remaining <- T - T.max
  n <- ceiling(T.remaining + 3*sqrt(T.remaining))
  #
  # Continue the Poisson process.
  #
  n.new <- rexp(n)
  n.t <- c(n.t, n.new)
  T.max <- T.max + sum(n.new)
}
#
# Sum the inter-arrival times and cut them off after time T.
#
n.t <- cumsum(n.t)
n.t <- n.t[n.t <= T]
#
# Generate the iid random values and accumulate their sums.
#
x <- c(0,cumsum(rnorm(length(n.t))))
#
# Display the result.
#
plot(stepfun(n.t, x), xlab="t", ylab="X", sub=paste("n =", length(n.t)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps me tremendously. Is it possible to get a nicer plot? i.e. one that does not display a circle around every point?

Comment: Yes: see the help page found at `?plot.stepfun`.  It tells you to include the argument `do.points=FALSE` when you invoke `plot` on the last line and it describes other options for controlling the appearance of the plot.